# Draft footnote changes position

Tags: header-footer, line-spacing, setspace

I use the `prelim2e` package to mark a document as a draft. This package puts a draft line below the normal footer that contains for example *Preliminary version – May 15, 2012*.

Usually this draft line stays at the same position on each page, except when the `singlespacing` environment is used. Then the draft line on the first page inside the `singlespacing` environment has little different position than the other draft lines. When flipping through the pages this looks weird and I would like to have the draft line in the exact same position on every page.

**Here is a MWE**

```
\documentclass[onehalfspacing,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{prelim2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{singlespacing}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\end{singlespacing}
\chapter{Some Chapter}    
\end{document}
```

**Positioning of draft line**

The positioning of the line is described in the [package documentation](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/special/prelim2e.pdf). But I am not really sure if and what I would have to change here:

> We put the text below the page via `\EveryShipout` provided by the
>   `everyshi` package. This is done by `\@Prelim@EveryShipout.`
>
> `\@Prelim@EveryShipout` puts the text produced by `\PrelimText` below
>   the page. To do this we modify `\box255`: We append a `\vbox` with height
>   and depth of 0pt and the width of `\box255` which contains a \hbox with
>   the width of `\box255` in which `\PrelimText` is centered.
>
> ```
> 38 \newcommand{\@Prelim@EveryShipout}{
> 39 \bgroup
> ```
>
> First we save the dimensions of `\box255`: height, width and depth;
>   and calculate the total height of `\box255`.
>
> ```
> 40 \dimen\z@=\wd\@cclv
> 41 \dimen\@ne=\ht\@cclv
> 42 \dimen\tw@=\dp\@cclv
> 43 \dimen\thr@@=\dimen1
> 44 \advance\dimen\thr@@ by \dimen\tw@
> ```
>
> Then we set `\box255`: A `\vbox` to the total height of `\box255`. In
>   this a `\hbox` to the width of `\box255` is included, in which
>   `\box255` is set.
>
> ```
> 45 \global\setbox\@cclv\vbox to \dimen\thr@@{%
> 46 \hb@xt@\dimen\z@{%
> 47 \box\@cclv%
> 48 \hss%
> 49 }%
> ```
>
> To this we append the text produced by `\PrelimText`. It is put in a
>   `\vbox` to `0pt` in which a `\hbox` to the width of `\box255` is
>   included, in which `\PrelimText` is set. We have to reset `\protect`
>   because it is set to `\noexpand` by the output routine.
>
> ```
> 50 \vbox to \z@{%
> 51 \hb@xt@\dimen\z@{%
> 52 \let\protect\relax
> 53 \hfill\PrelimText\hfill%
> 54 }%
> 55 \vss%
> 56 }%
> 57 \vss%
> 58 }%
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have another solution which does use the package `background` instead of your used package `prelim2e`. It does not affect your layout of your pages, it just writes a message in the background of your pages. Have a look to this MWE:

```
\documentclass[onehalfspacing,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[contents=Confidential,color=blue!30]{background}
%\usepackage[contents=Confidential,color=blue!30,placement=bottom]{background}
\usepackage[%
  color=blue!30
 ,scale=4
]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={Preliminary version – May 15, 2012}}

\begin{document}
\begin{singlespacing}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\end{singlespacing}
\chapter{Some Chapter}    
\end{document}
```

The two commented lines shows alternative calls of package `background`.

Comment: Combining the backgroundpackage with the ifdraft command does a better job than prelim2e.