# Prelim2e marking but centred without tikz

Tags: horizontal-alignment, geometry, backgrounds, draft, prelim2e

I use preliminary markup on draft versions of documents which specifies the `svn` repository number, timestamp, url etc. I prefer this to be typeset centred at the bottom of the page below the footer.

Here is the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image: desiderata]

The solution needs to:

- work in both `onecolumn` and `twocolumn` mode;
- work with at least the standard LaTeX classes;
- work with `geometry` and `fancyhdr`;
- allow LaTeX commands in the specification of the preliminary marker so I can typeset `svn` information, `\today` etc. and allow multi-line markers;
- centre the marker beneath the footer but within the printable area even when different options are passed to `geometry` and `fancyhdr`;
- be sensitive to whether the `draft` or `final` option is active;
- not affect page layout in other ways e.g. it must not affect page or line breaks, alignment or placement of the header/footer;
- work with pdfLaTeX.

I have been using `prelim2e`. However, this does not centre the marking beneath the footer consistently or correctly. This prompted me to ask [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171949/why-does-increasing-hscale-produce-overfull-hbox). Although there is something odd about `geometry`'s effect there, it seems that there is also a distinct issue with `prelim2e` in the sense that no matter what I try, I cannot get the markup centred beneath the footer. This is true even if I stick to the very simplest configuration and just try something like `\PrelimWords{a}`.

After searching this site and ctan for a bit, I came across maetra's comment on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78611/39222). That comment suggests combining `background` and `ifdraft`. So I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[draft,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{url,svn-multi}
    \svnidlong
        {$HeadURL: file:///svn/myproject/tweaked-branch/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/tex/latex/something/something.sty $}
        {$LastChangedBy: cfr $}
        {$LastChangedRevision: 19567 $}
        {$LastChangedDate: 2014-04-16 19:46:05 +0100 (Mer, 16 Ebr 2014) $}
\usepackage[hscale=.875]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\makeatletter
  \ifdraft{%
    \usepackage[placement=bottom,scale=1,opacity=1,vshift=10mm]{background}
      \@ifpackageloaded{svn-multi}{%
          \newsavebox{\prelimtxt}
          \sbox{\prelimtxt}{%
              \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                      \urlstyle{sf}%
                      \centering \small \textsf{Draft --- \today\ --- Revision \svnrev\ --- \svnyear--\svnmonth--\svnday\ \svnhour:\svnminute:\svnsecond}\\[1em]
                      \centering \tiny \textsf{\svnkw{HeadURL}}\\%
                      }% end parbox
              }% end sbox
          \backgroundsetup{contents=\usebox{\prelimtxt}}
          }{\backgroundsetup{contents={\centering \small \textsf{Draft --- pdf\LaTeX{}ed --- \today}}}}}{%
          \providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{\relax}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Although I have not yet tried this in a real document, the results appear to be exactly what I'm looking for. The output is, in fact, that I posted above.

However, it does seem to be a sledgehammer to crack a nut. This solution requires me to load `tikz` merely to set the preliminary marker at the bottom of the page. I realise this is because `background` is much more powerful and flexible than `prelim2e` and I really like the package for other uses. It just feels like overkill here. (Note that much of my customisation is dedicated to *undoing* the doings of `background` by setting the scale back to 1, using full opacity etc.)

Moreover, this solution requires me to either put up with errors when switching to final or to load `tikz` even when I'm not using it at all. (My code above institutes a hack to avoid both evils which involves just setting a dummy command if necessary.)

Is there an alternative solution which works properly but is a bit lighter weight? Or a workaround for `prelim2e` (seems doubtful from what I've read)?

Comment: I was using `picture` environment to move a wanted material to a new position on page, but it is relative positioning, it needed a fixed point. I was thinking about [`zwpagelayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zwpagelayout) package for a minute but it primarily focuses on crop marks. I would be thinking about [`pst-abspos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-abspos) and [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) packages, but you are trying to avoid them. I jumped from current fixed position to page center in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171500/how-to-print-a0-poster-as-an-array-of-combinable-a4-pages/

Comment: @Malipivo Although it doesn't seem to like the `landscape` environment. Also, I had to fiddle a bit to get it to work with other things. I guess one can't have everything... ;)

Comment: Please try `pdflscape` package, or, try `\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth` and `\pdfpageheight=\paperheight` directly at some point before calculations. It usually costs me a headache.

Comment: @Malipivo I suspect I'll just live with it. I already use `pdflscape` and the calculations are done at the beginning of the document whereas I'm then screwing it up by setting a particular page in `landscape`. `prelim2e` somehow manages this but I think I might just set the pagestyle to empty! Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Malipivo's comment, I thought that I might try using `eso-pic` directly. This is the package `prelim2e` uses but I wondered if the placement problems might be an artefact of `prelim2e` rather than a problem with the underlying framework provided by `eso-pic` itself. After playing with this for a little, things started to go better...

This solution uses `eso-pic`, `calc` and `ifdraft` but does not require `background` or, therefore, `tikz`. It works with pdfLaTeX (not just LaTeX), centres the preliminary marker at the bottom beneath the footer and should not affect the layout, page or line breaking. It works with `geometry`, `fancyhdr`, both `onecolumn` and `twocolumn`, and is sensitive to the `final`/`draft` option thanks to `ifdraft`.

I'm sure there's a catch somewhere but the MWE looks good...

```
\documentclass[draft,twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{url,svn-multi}
    \svnidlong
        {$HeadURL: file:///svn/myproject/tweaked-branch/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/tex/latex/something/something.sty $}
        {$LastChangedBy: cfr $}
        {$LastChangedRevision: 19567 $}
        {$LastChangedDate: 2014-04-16 19:46:05 +0100 (Mer, 16 Ebr 2014) $}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifdraft{%
        \usepackage{eso-pic}
        \usepackage{calc}
        \newsavebox{\prelimtxt}
        \@ifpackageloaded{svn-multi}{%
            \sbox{\prelimtxt}{%
                \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
                    \urlstyle{sf}%
                    \centering
                    \sffamily
                    \small
                    Draft --- \today\ --- Revision \svnrev\ --- \svnyear--\svnmonth--\svnday\ \svnhour:\svnminute:\svnsecond\\[.5em]
                    \tiny
                    \svnkw{HeadURL}\\%
                    }% end parbox
                }% end sbox
           }{%
             \sbox{\prelimtxt}{%
               \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
                   \centering \small \textsf{Draft --- pdf\LaTeX{}ed --- \today}%
                   }% end parbox
                }% end sbox
          }% end ifpackageloaded
          \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
            \begingroup
              \settototalheight{\@tempdima}{\usebox{\prelimtxt}}%
              \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth-.5\textwidth}%
              \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight-.5\textheight-.5\headheight-.5\headsep-.5\footskip-.5\@tempdima}%
              \put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdimb},\LenToUnit{\@tempdimc}){%
                \usebox{\prelimtxt}}%
            \endgroup
            }% end AddToShipoutPictureBG
            }{}% end ifdraft
  }
\makeatother
\usepackage[hscale=.875]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhf[lh]{\emph{Immanuel Kant}}
  \fancyhf[rh]{\emph{My Musings}}
  \fancyhf[cf]{\emph{--- \thepage ---}}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Centred preliminary markings without <code>tikz</code>]

The code below deals, I think, with the case where the `landscape` environment is used to typeset selected pages in landscape orientation. The code has `showframe` set for `geometry` and this gives an extremely puzzling result on page 2 (which is landscape). This is pretty horrible, in any case. Is there really no better solution than mine?!

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{url,svn-multi}
    \svnidlong
        {$HeadURL: file:///svn/myproject/tweaked-branch/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/tex/latex/something/something.sty $}
        {$LastChangedBy: cfr $}
        {$LastChangedRevision: 19567 $}
        {$LastChangedDate: 2014-04-16 19:46:05 +0100 (Mer, 16 Ebr 2014) $}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifdraft{%
        \usepackage{eso-pic}
        \usepackage{calc}
        \newlength{\origtextwidth}%
        \newlength{\origtextheight}%
        \setlength{\origtextwidth}{\textwidth}%
        \setlength{\origtextheight}{\textheight}%
        \newsavebox{\prelimtxt}
        \@ifpackageloaded{svn-multi}{%
            \sbox{\prelimtxt}{%
                \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
                    \urlstyle{sf}%
                    \centering
                    \sffamily
                    \small
                    Draft --- \today\ --- Revision \svnrev\ --- \svnyear--\svnmonth--\svnday\ \svnhour:\svnminute:\svnsecond\\[.5em]
                    \tiny
                    \svnkw{HeadURL}\\%
                    }% end parbox
                }% end sbox
           }{%
             \sbox{\prelimtxt}{%
               \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
                   \centering \small \textsf{Draft --- pdf\LaTeX{}ed --- \today}%
                   }% end parbox
                }% end sbox
          }% end ifpackageloaded
          \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
            \begingroup
              \settototalheight{\@tempdima}{\usebox{\prelimtxt}}%
              \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth-.5\origtextwidth}%
              \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight-.5\origtextheight-.5\headheight-.5\headsep-.5\footskip-.5\@tempdima}%
              \put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdimb},\LenToUnit{\@tempdimc}){%
                \usebox{\prelimtxt}}%
            \endgroup
            }% end AddToShipoutPictureBG
            }{}% end ifdraft
  }
\makeatother
\usepackage[hscale=.875,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhf[lh]{\emph{Immanuel Kant}}
  \fancyhf[rh]{\emph{My Musings}}
  \fancyhf[cf]{\emph{--- \thepage ---}}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\begin{landscape}
      \kant[6-10]
\end{landscape}
\kant[11-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: landscape lunacy]

This was prompted by Malipivo's comment that `\textwidth=\textheight` within the landscape ship out environment. This is illustrated by the frame on page 2 above. The only way I could figure out to place the markings correctly despite this was to save the lengths at the beginning of the document in macros for use as constants in the ship out environment. (I also tried modifying the `landscape` environment. Although that works I don't think it has any benefit.)

Comment: Well done! I tried `landscape` (paper) and it looks fine. I will try `landscape` env. in a minute...

Comment: @Malipivo Thanks! I'm not entirely satisfied. Apart from the landscape thing, I'm not convinced I'm calculating the vertical placement correctly. (There's no pleasing some people - first I complain about the horizontal, now I moan about the vertical.) I tried using `geometry`'s layout diagrams but it doesn't end up where I think it should. [I wanted it to always be equidistant from the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the page but it doesn't seem to work - not quite - so I must have misunderstood somewhere.)

Comment: I am measuring `\textwidth` and `\textheight` as equal inside the `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` command, that's strange and `geometry` is not to be blamed, it is turned off. It is probably causing `eso-pic`. There is worse thing/bug, when I use `\usepackage[hscale=.875]{geometry}` then in `landscape` environment I am completely losing the second and following pages in that environment.

Comment: @Malipivo Hmmm... How do you find out what the values are within `\AddToShipoutPictureBG`?

Comment: @Malipivo I can't reproduce the loss of text. Things are misplaced in the `landscape` environment but it is all there as far as I can tell. (Obviously I get fewer pages due to the increase in `hscale`. So I created 5 pages with the 2nd in `landscape`. When I adjust `hscale`, I get 4 pages with stuff mislocated on page 2 but I don't seem to lose anything...

Comment: @Malipivo See my edit?! Weird... Try passing `geometry` `showframe` to see why it claims `\textwidth=\textheight` in the `landscape` environment. I can't figure out how to extract the values but I can *see*...

Comment: @Malipivo Sorry for all the comments but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115908/39222.

Comment: I am using `\typeout{\the\textwidth, \the\textheight, \the\pdfpagewidth, \the\pdfpageheight}`. After that I can read dimensions from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP realized there is a known [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115908/39222) known as a ["design comprimise"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110954/tabulary-on-a-rotated-page-does-not-use-correct-textwidth/110959#comment244075_110959) between [`lscape`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lscape)/[`pdflscape`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) and the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) packages (I know [Zdeněk Wagner](http://icebearsoft.euweb.cz/index-en.php), the author of the [`zwpagelayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zwpagelayout) package, in person, I would use his package instead of [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) under normal circumstances), I tried to find another strategy even if I like shifting from the fixed position very much.

I put all the information right below the page number directly by redefining the footer center using the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package. I neither need [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) nor [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) packages anymore. It is working well, but we are losing the last page in the `landscape` environment. It is working again if we change either:

- `\usepackage[hscale=.875]{geometry}` to `\usepackage{geometry}`, or,
- we turn off `twocolumn` parameter in the line with `\documentclass`.

I found a patch to this: let's use `\onecolumn` before `\begin{landscape}` and `\twocolumn` after `\end{landscape}`. It improved things a lot, but there is still one issue to be solved that we don't have two columns in the `landscape` environment, yet. We could try `\twocolumn` inside this environment but we would get two columns on top of each other. Therefore I turned on the `multicol` package and here we are.

I enclose an example and a preview of 8 pages, we can run any major `latex` engine. It works with [`lscape`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lscape) and [`pdflscape`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) packages.

```
% run: *latex mal-hsize.tex
\documentclass[draft,twocolumn,a4paper]{article} % draft twocolumn
\usepackage[hscale=.875]{geometry} %[hscale=.875]
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{svn-multi}
\ifx\svnidlong\undefined 
    \relax
\else
    \svnidlong
        {$HeadURL: file:///svn/myproject/tweaked-branch/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/tex/latex/something/something.sty $}
        {$LastChangedBy: cfr $}
        {$LastChangedRevision: 19567 $}
        {$LastChangedDate: 2014-04-16 19:46:05 +0100 (Mer, 16 Ebr 2014) $}
\fi

\def\measureme{%
  \scrollmode % show me information...
  \typeout{%
    page: \thepage^^J%
    textwidth and textheight: \the\textwidth, \the\textheight,^^J%
    pdfpagewidth and pdfpageheight: \the\pdfpagewidth, \the\pdfpageheight%
  }% End of \typeout...
  \batchmode % don't show me new information...
  }% End of \measureme...

\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhf[lh]{\emph{Immanuel Kant}}
  \fancyhf[rh]{\emph{My Musings}}
  %\fancyhf[cf]{\emph{--- \thepage ---}}

\ifdraft{%
\newbox\malbox
  \ifx\svnidlong\undefined 
  \setbox\malbox=\hbox{%
               \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
                   \centering \small \textsf{Draft --- pdf\LaTeX{}ed --- \today}%
                   }% End of \parbox...
                }% End of \setbox...
\else
  \setbox\malbox=\hbox{%
                \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
                    \urlstyle{sf}%
                    \centering
                    \sffamily
                    \small
                    Draft --- \today\ --- Revision \svnrev\ --- \svnyear--\svnmonth--\svnday\ \svnhour:\svnminute:\svnsecond\\[.5em]
                    \tiny
                    \svnkw{HeadURL}\\%
                    }% End of \parbox...
                }% End of \setbox...
  \fi
  \fancyfoot[C]{\measureme\emph{--- \thepage\ --- \\[9pt] \copy\malbox}%
}%
  }{\relax}% End of \ifdraft...
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-7]

\onecolumn % a patch, part 1
\begin{landscape}
%\twocolumn :-)
\begin{multicols}{2}
\kant[6-26]
\end{multicols}
\end{landscape}
\twocolumn % a patch, part 2

\kant[1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, part 1]

[image: mwe, part 2]

Comment: +1 for such a detailed and careful answer. I'd never heard of `zwpagelayout` but it seems to be a really interesting package. (`geometry` is probably easier to use for my purposes but that's a different story.) I'm not sure what the best approach is right now. I actually created this problem in the first place by attempting to move *away* from `multicols` (which was part of my previous solution) because of its limitations in handling floats. This is one of those cases in which I feel that every time I fix one problem, I create another...

Comment: I see, I usually escape `multicols` environment, place floating bodies in the document and return to the `multicols` environment. But this area is quite complex, it depends a lot on the actual problem.